# Dual booted but Windows 7 do not open

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I am new to Ubuntu and I think I made a mistake while installing it along side window 7.  First `grub` didn't show Windows as an option so I fixed it but now windows gets stuck on loading screen and never opens.

Here is the result of `sudo fdisk -l`

```
/dev/sda1  *           2048 886458367 886456320 422,7G 83 Linux

/dev/sda3         886460414 976771071  90310658  43,1G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)

/dev/sda5         886460416 945851040  59390625  28,3G 83 Linux

/dev/sda6         945852416 976771071  30918656  14,8G 82 Linux takas / Solaris
```

Windows option is `sda1` but I think I corrupted the files somehow. Could anyone please help me fix it?

Thanks in advance! :D

Edit:thank you all for your answers but the problem was gone the next time i opened the laptop.what they say about ubuntu users is right i guess,you guys are amazing

Comment: If you ever changed your partitions to "dynamic" in Windows, a Microsoft proprietary thing, those aren't supported in Linux.

Comment: You show sda1 as Linux formatted, Windows can only be NTFS formatted. If you have any data you did not backup STOP using system. You may be able to recover some, but not all data.https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible mistakes
1.your dual boot was not actually done as dual boot
2.while allocating free memory u might have converted all disc to logical memory from primary memory
3.u overwrote ubuntu over windows...(but if u can access windows C drive from Ubuntu then this is not case)
4.one of the operating system is in legacy mode and one of them is in UEFI mode //more chances(if this is the case only one of the OS will boot(one which is in default BOOT mode-see it in BIOS Menu) ).u will have to reinstall them both properly in same mode)

Comment: If this solves your problem..plz accept solution.t y